# sql select all columns from column X onwards

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgrest

I have this table that has around 50 columns, whereas the first 5 columns specify some meta information, but for the rest of the columns I process them in a generic manner. Is there a sql command to select all columns from column 5 onwards without specifying each column individually?

Comment: There is no pre-written SQL that will do what you want. You have 3 choices: 1. List the columns or interest.  (The proper way.) 2. Select all the columns and discard/hide the meta columns in your apps presentation manager.  3. Write a procedure that queries the table from `information schema` and builds a SQL statement that selects the column of interest; then run the statement constructed. The first two have the advantage of being a single statement. For the third you will need to research *dynamic sql.

Comment: Columns do not have an order so no.

Answer (score 0):

No.

It doesn't really make sense in a relational model to talk about "generic columns".